# Split csv files based on columns

Tags: python, csv, weka

I have a csv file that I am trying to split based on the number of columns. The original file has about 24000 columns and I want to split this into files with each files having a fixed number of columns (say 1000). I want to run to do feature selection on weka on the individual files. I have the following code in python.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

i=0
df=pd.read_csv("glio.csv")
#row_split=int(input("Enter the Row Split: "))
row_split=6000
name ="temp_file_"
ext=".csv"
rows, columns = df.shape
df_temp=df.iloc[:,:row_split]
df_temp.to_csv(name+str(i)+ext)
i=i+1
while(row_split<columns):
    df_temp=df.iloc[:,row_split+1:row_split+100]
    df_temp.to_csv(name+str(i)+ext)
    i=i+1
    row_split+=1000
```

It is generating the individual files as expected but after splitting I am not able to load the individual files in weka. I am getting the following error

[image]

I am new to this and have no idea why this occurs. I cannot find answers online. It would be really helpful if someone could explain why this is happening and how to correct this

Comment: Unfortunately you don't really give us enough information to help you. The problem may be with the way you are creating the data or the way you are trying to use `weka`, or it might be something else. I'd recommend testing your program with a small dataset, that you can easily control to give expected results, before trying to handle large volumes.

Comment: Answer by AndreyF fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add index=False to the `to_csv` call:

```
df_temp.to_csv(name+str(i)+ext, index=False)
```

Also please upload a screenshot of the csv file when you open it in some csv viewer application (e.g. Excel).